# How to implement basic web authentication in SwiftUI App for a specific web service that does not provide an API?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, swiftui, urlsession

I will get straight to the point. Please excuse my english

So there is a website (we can call it X) which offers a service to query and fetch documents etc after logging in with your username / password

I am trying to figure out a way to, basically, provide the same service except natively through the app. The user of the app will still have to enter their username and password and then I make a request to the website and "log" in and then provide the same interface the website does after logging in but the app will be able to save the login information and be able to have some other features that would be beneficial wrt to the documents that it then fetches.

The website does not offer an api (atleast that I know of) I am struggling to figure out how to send the URL request with the username and password.
First I read about using ASAuthenticationServices but that led me to reading that you need the callback url which did not work for me (1. because I can't setup the callback url through the API and 2. because my custom app callback url did not fire)
Then I tried to use a WKWebView to embed a browser and a try to catch the details after the user logged in but still no success.

I have also read that JWT might be the solution considering that it is only a single server authentication needed

This is my code so far, I have stripped it down to basically just show the request I'm making
If anyone could shed some light as to how to perform a simple web login (to basically embed the web service and be able to use it as an app) I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

So this is where I'm at now. I'm trying to form a URLRequest and just checking whether the signin response works, should I be trying to implement a callback in a custom WKWebView ? I'm more kind of asking as to what method I should be using. Should I be researching more into JWT ? or should I be looking at using custom WKWebViews and trying to catch the callback and save the credentials etc through that or do I need to just deconstruct and send custom URLRequests in order to authenticate? thank you

```
import Combine
import Foundation

final class SignInDummy: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var username = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    
    @Published var hasError = false
    
    @Published var isSigningIn = false
    
    var canSignIn: Bool {
        !username.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty
    }
    
    func signIn() {
        guard !username.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        let url = URL(string: "https:// URL to website (copy and pasted url of the login page)")!
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let authData = (username + ":" + password).data(using: .utf8)!.base64EncodedString()
        request.addValue("Basic \(authData)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        isSigningIn = true
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                if error != nil || (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode != 200 {
                    self?.hasError = true
                } else if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let signInResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(SignInResponse.self, from: data)
                        
                        print(signInResponse)
                        
                            // TODO: Cache Access Token in Keychain
                    } catch {
                        print("Unable to Decode Response \(error)")
                        
                        print("\(response?.mimeType)")
                        
                        print("\(response.debugDescription)")

                        
                    }
                }
                
                self?.isSigningIn = false
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    fileprivate struct SignInResponse: Decodable {
        
            // MARK: - Properties
        
        let accessToken: String
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't deal with web authentication

Comment: Typically authentication is not just 1 request: it's a workflow of several requests. And how it operates (i.e. should you use SSO via WebView, or requests) depends entirely on an authentication provider (i.e. that site you try to access). Also if you are not explicitly allowed by site owners to have such app / login (via API license/ token or any other way), then you are basically doing something illegal.

Comment: So the website I'm trying to implement this for is a local website of a global api product by InterSystems. Although I have not personally asked as to whether I could provide login via the app I know that there is an app on the app store (in my region) that currently does do this. If I could just figure how lol, I'm hoping to provide a cleaner UI and more features.

Comment: @loremipsum yeah should change to Swift, anyways looking for information wrt to any implementations in swift utilising these network services